# "recursive" query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

this is my current query :

```
SELECT
    id, name,
    CASE 
        when geolocation='' then (select geolocation from location where id = q1.parent_id)
        else geolocation end
FROM location q1;
```

this is an example of the table on which i make my query and the current result i get:

```
id | name | geolocation | parent_id 
-- | ---- | ----------- | ---------
 1 | aaaa |   0.0,0.0   |    
 2 | bbbb |   1.1,1.1   |     1
 3 | cccc |             |     1
 4 | dddd |   2.2,2.2   |  
 5 | eeee |             |
 6 | ffff |             |     3
```

```
id | name | geolocation 
-- | ---- | ----------- 
 1 | aaaa |   0.0,0.0   
 2 | bbbb |   1.1,1.1   
 3 | cccc |   0.0,0.0        
 4 | dddd |   2.2,2.2    
 5 | eeee |   
 6 | ffff |
```

this is not the result i want to get. what i would like is the request to be "recursive" so that the 6th location gets the geolocation of the "root parent" (in this case location aaaa). so my expected result is :

```
id | name | geolocation 
-- | ---- | ----------- 
 1 | aaaa |   0.0,0.0   
 2 | bbbb |   1.1,1.1   
 3 | cccc |   0.0,0.0        
 4 | dddd |   2.2,2.2    
 5 | eeee |   
 6 | ffff |   0.0,0.0
```

i tried to use the "cte method" but i can't get the result i want...

anyone has an idea?

best regards and have a great day

ps : careful, geolocation is a string

Comment: If you need to support a hierarchical structure of data - this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/38701519/5962802

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\i tmp.sql

CREATE TABLE wtf
        ( id integer PRIMARY KEY
        , name text
        , geolocation text
        , parent_id integer REFERENCES wtf(id)
        );

INSERT INTO wtf
        ( id , name , geolocation , parent_id ) VALUES
  (1 ,'aaaa' ,'0.0,0.0',NULL)
 , (2 ,'bbbb' ,'1.1,1.1',1)
 , (3 ,'cccc' ,'',1)
 , (4 ,'dddd' ,'2.2,2.2', NULL )
 , (5 ,'eeee' ,'',NULL)
 , (6 ,'ffff' ,'',3 )
        ;

SELECT * FROM wtf;

        -- find the "root" (if any) for all entries
WITH RECURSIVE opa AS (
        SELECT id AS opa
        , id AS moi
        FROM wtf
        WHERE parent_id IS NULL -- The roots
    UNION
        SELECT o.opa AS opa -- inherit the root name from your parent
                ,m.id AS moi
        FROM wtf m -- the descendants
        JOIN opa o ON (m.parent_id = o.moi)
        )
SELECT w.*
        , x.name AS opa_name
        , x.geolocation AS opa_geolocation
FROM wtf w
JOIN opa o ON (w.id = o.moi)
LEFT JOIN wtf x ON (x.id = o.opa)
        ;
```

---

Results:

---

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 6
 id | name | geolocation | parent_id 
----+------+-------------+-----------
  1 | aaaa | 0.0,0.0     |          
  2 | bbbb | 1.1,1.1     |         1
  3 | cccc |             |         1
  4 | dddd | 2.2,2.2     |          
  5 | eeee |             |          
  6 | ffff |             |         3
(6 rows)

 id | name | geolocation | parent_id | opa_name | opa_geolocation 
----+------+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------------
  1 | aaaa | 0.0,0.0     |           | aaaa     | 0.0,0.0
  4 | dddd | 2.2,2.2     |           | dddd     | 2.2,2.2
  5 | eeee |             |           | eeee     | 
  2 | bbbb | 1.1,1.1     |         1 | aaaa     | 0.0,0.0
  3 | cccc |             |         1 | aaaa     | 0.0,0.0
  6 | ffff |             |         3 | aaaa     | 0.0,0.0
(6 rows)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer @wildplasser, works perfectly fine. just added this query in the end to get the final result : 
```
SELECT 
    id, name,
    CASE 
        when geolocation = '' then opa_geolocation
        else geolocation end as geolocation
FROM this_intermediate
ORDER BY id asc;
```
thank you again and have a great day, best regards.

Comment: Yes, you could use `COALESCE()` to massage the final results. (cleaner than the CASE expression) NOTE: `opa` is Dutch for `grandpere` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The first idea is to use a function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION get_last_location(int) RETURNS text
    AS $$ 

       WITH RECURSIVE subordinates AS 
        (
         SELECT
         id,parent_id, name,geolocation from location 
         WHERE
         id =$1

         UNION

         SELECT
           e.id,e.parent_id, e.name,e.geolocation from location e
          inner JOIN subordinates s ON s.parent_id = e.id
        )
    select geolocation from subordinates 
    where not (geolocation is null) order by id limit 1
    
    $$
    LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Then use this select:

```
SELECT
    id, name,
    CASE 
        when geolocation is null then (select get_last_location(q1.id))
        else geolocation end
FROM location q1;
```

The query without using function

```
SELECT
    id, name,
    CASE 
        when geolocation is null then 
        (
               WITH RECURSIVE subordinates AS 
                  (
                   SELECT
                   id,parent_id, name,geolocation from location 
                   WHERE
                   id =q1.id

                   UNION

                   SELECT
                     e.id,e.parent_id, e.name,e.geolocation from location e
                    inner JOIN subordinates s ON s.parent_id = e.id
                  )
                  select geolocation from subordinates 
                  where not (geolocation is null) order by id limit 1
        
        )
        else geolocation end
FROM location q1;
```

The Output

[image]

Comment: hi @MitkoKeckaroski, thank you for your answer, but it only works with id 1 or am I wrong ? i would like something "generic" that does it for each parent...

Comment: just add the id of any element in the WERE condition

Comment: ok i see, the problem is that my table is dynamic so that would not work...

Comment: no idea on how to do it without specifying the "root" id ?

Comment: @ArmandViolle: typically the "root id" is defined by using `where parent_id is null`

Comment: i'm dumb... i'm tryning your query with this "where" clause. tell you if it works

Comment: still doesn't work.. sorry for wasting your time

Comment: @MitkoKeckaroski thank you, last question : is there a way to do it without creating a function ?

Comment: @Armand Violle,   yes, check in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
  r AS (
      SELECT id, name, geolocation
      FROM location
      WHERE parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
      SELECT
        l.id,
        l.name,
        COALESCE(l.geolocation,
                 r.geolocation)
      FROM r
      JOIN location AS l
        ON r.id = l.parent_id
  )
SELECT * FROM r;
```

Result:

```
+----+------+-------------+
| id | name | geolocation |
+----+------+-------------+
|  1 | aaaa | 0.0,0.0     |
|  4 | dddd | 2.2,2.2     |
|  5 | eeee |             |
|  2 | bbbb | 1.1,1.1     |
|  3 | cccc | 0.0,0.0     |
|  6 | ffff | 0.0,0.0     |
+----+------+-------------+
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f89f1f787b366bcfff86d5d249dcf344)

Comment: Ogedov  I tried the exact same thing before asking the question thinking it would work too, but it doesn't... thanks for your answer